# Use Spring as object factory for Morphia

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, guice, morphia

I need to inject some fields to objects loaded from Mongo via Morphia using `@Autowired` annotations. I found an example how that's made with Guice:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(...);
MapperOptions options = injector.getInstance(Morphia.class)
        .getMapper()
        .getOptions();
options.setObjectFactory(new GuiceObjectFactory(
    options.getObjectFactory(),
    injector
));
```

So they use `GuiceObjectFactory`. Is there anything alike in Spring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not included in Morphia but the implementation is pretty straightforward.  [Here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/39a5dde3a0fd1dcbf857d7adc4e46fb80f0e671a/guice-plug/src/main/java/org/mongodb/morphia/ext/guice/GuiceObjectFactory.java#L42) you can see what's happening for Guice.  Other than asking the `injector` to create the instance, there's not much that really needs to happen.